# Why is my computer overheating? Is my CPU or Graphics Card damaged?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, hardware-failure, overheating

A few months ago my computer began freezing and crashing. I don't get a bluescreen, just suddenly turns off when it crashes. Sometimes it turns off when it freezes, and other times I have to reset it. It usually freezes during videos or videogames, especially cut scenes... though videos from certain sites like Youtube work fine. And I can play certain video games as well and they don't bother it.

I've already tried replacing the power supply and applying new thermal paste to the CPU, but this hasn't helped. I tried switching a different Hard disk with Windows on it but I got a blue screen when it tried to start up... though that hard disk has been sitting around for a long time; I can't verify that it would work anyway.

As you can see below, TMPIN2 on the motherboard heats up when I run the diagnostic or play a video game. From what I've found, TMPIN2 is CPU. I'd suspected the graphics card but this seems to indicate that its the CPU. I want to get more opinions before I go and buy another CPU.
[Here is data from CPUID Hardware Monitor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lg9E.png)

Edit: I've tried updating graphics card driver and I've scanned thoroughly for viruses as well. The replacing the hard drive was my final attempt to make sure it wasn't a software issue.

Edit2: Even if I using an overclocking tool to turn down my CPU, it doesn't help... this makes me question whether it is the CPU.

Comment: Look, carefully, for lint, hair or other stuff blocking the ventilation ducts or the fan itself. Some laptops are ludicrously poorly designed for the real (filthy) world.

Comment: I'd tried spraying out my fan with an air can earlier. That didn't help, but now sucked at it with a vacuum and that actually fixed my overheating problem.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a result of inadequate cooling, not a damaged or faulty CPU.

I would look into non-stock heatsink fans or watercooling for the CPU, potentially also the graphics card if you want to.
Meanwhile, be sure to do some of these:

- If you use an air-cooled case, make sure all exhaust fans are clean and free of obstruction
- Make sure your case isn't enclosed (e.g. in a desk cabinet) and the intake fans are also free of dust and obstruction.
- Make sure you're utilizing proper cable management inside the case - a mess of cables can restrict air flow.
- Make sure your case fan is plugged into the motherboard
- Double-check that your case fans are spinning
- Double-check that your graphics cards fans are spinning (make sure if you have a special card like the MSI GTX 970 that the temperature on the card is high enough for the fans to activate)

The last time I had a system completely shut off on me, it was because my graphics card's fans were damaged and the system would overheat to the point of shutting off.

Answer (score 0):

Over heating of system can be linked with multiple issues Like Bad fan, Damaged processor, Room temperature, Bad Ram. Dust clotting on Fan.

First of all dissemble all the hardwares from your Cpu and clean all the dust clotting from hardware parts.

Secondly use original heatsink on top of processor, third check and test the fan speed. If not found perfect replace it with new original, fourth check out for bad capacitors in motherboard. Fifth check out Smps. Unbalanced power supply may also lead to heating of system.

Hope above pointed points will fix your issue.